# Threshold method to detect dynamically red from orange

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, colors

I want to be able to dynamically separate the orange parts from the red parts on my images. At the moment I'm using ranges but the problem with ranges is that they are fixed and the images can arrive with bad quality and the orange parts become a little bit more red or the red parts become a little bit more orange but still these parts remain recognizable and differentiable to the naked eye. And I'm thinking of using a threshold to be able to determine these colours dynamically but I can't do it. Do you have any ideas for me?

[image]

It can happen that the image comes with a less good quality and that the red part is not so red anymore but until then you can still differentiate the different parts very well. And then when I try your answer it doesn't do exactly what it should.

[image]

Comment: you're using "ranges"? provide details on that (i.e. code). you should work in HSV space.

Comment: I already work in HSV space. When I talk about "ranges" I mean
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 20, 0), (13, 255, 255))
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (160, 20, 0), (180, 255, 255))

Comment: try k-means clustering then, k=3 for background and two foregrounds (or k=2 if you select only foreground pixels). hopefully it does the right thing. you can run that on RGB tuples or on HSV tuples. perhaps run ImageJ and visually explore a color histogram of your data.

Comment: otsu thresholding might work as well, if you transform the color space into something where the primary axis expresses yellow/orange vs. red/pink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have clean images such as the one provided without noisy background and you want to separate the colors **Red**, and **Orange** which is **Red + Green**, I suggest to do **thresholding** on the **green channel** where the difference between the two colors can be seen well:

[image: res]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input.png')
green = img[...,1]

mask = cv2.threshold(green, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

Orange = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

Red = img - Orange

res = np.concatenate((Orange, Red), axis=1)

cv2.namedWindow('Result', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Result', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It can happen that the image comes with a less good quality and that the red part is not so red anymore but until then you can still differentiate the different parts very well. And then when I try your answer it doesn't do exactly what it should.

Comment: @cedrik24 the **more general is the solution the less accurate it is**, hence you can do [contrast adjustment](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html) for the `green channel`  **before** the `otsu thresholding`, but the quality of the separation will not be perfect!